# How to get all threads ready and send all of them at once

Tags: python, python-requests, python-multithreading

Is there any way to improve performance of Python script by making all threads ready and sending all of them at once?

For example, "get ready" 100 different threads with HTTP requests, and when they are ready, they will be released at the same time with smallest delay possible.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any possibility to make all threads ready (for example 500 threads) and send all of them without waiting?

Yes.

What you need is a [synchronization object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html). Basically you start all threads, but they try to acquire access to a resource, which is not possible initially. When all 500 threads are waiting, you release that resource and all 500 threads will run.

Please note that

- on usual computers, you can only run 8 threads really parallel, because the CPU only has 8 cores. So starting 500 threads and having 1 HTTP request each will likely result in the same as running 8 threads that do 62 HTTP requests in a loop.
- specifically for Python, it has the GIL (global interpreter lock), so you don't need multithreading, you need multiprocessing.
- this seems to be used for load testing. There's software available which was specifically built for such purposes, they are reliable and tested. Don't reinvent the wheel, that's error prone.
- Thread scheduling on Windows is done in 17 ms intervals, AFAIK. That's because there is a hardware timer causing an interrupt. This interrupt gives the kernel control over the CPU. So your 10 ms requirements may not be possible.